# appengine 1.7.4 sdk and com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

i have upgraded to appengine 1.7.4 and something is now broken.

when deploying to local dev the appengine errors with the following.

```
Class "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager" was not found in the C
LASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class "com.google.appengin
e.datanucleus.DatastoreManager" was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check you
r specification and your CLASSPATH.
```

This is NOT a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but a    org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException

my libs are

```
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.4  
appengine-api-labs-1.7.4  
datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.0-m3  
datanucleus-api-jpa-3.2.0-m3  
datanucleus-appengine-2.1.1  
datanucleus-core-3.2.0-m3  
datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1
```

it is build using maven.

the DataNucleus App Engine Plugin Compatibility
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility
states

```
3.0:
Requires DataNucleus 3.2+ (core, api-jdo, api-jpa).
Requires SDK 1.7.0+
```

The datanucleus-appengine-2.1.1 pom has dependancies of

```
org.datanucleus datanucleus-api-jdo [3.1.1, 3.2)  
org.datanucleus datanucleus-api-jpa [3.1.1, 3.2)  
org.datanucleus datanucleus-core    [3.1.1, 3.2)  
org.datanucleus datanucleus-enhancer    [3.1.0-release, )
```

something is wrong with the version of the libs but i cant determine it.
what is the correct dependency for DN plugin and the sdk 1.7.4?

-lp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why have you got "datanucleus-api-jdo" AND "datanucleus-api-jpa" in the CLASSPATH? Decide which API you're using and use that one. Where are the other dependencies ? jdo-api.jar of persistence-api.jar ?

You can't use DataNUcleus 3.2 unless you're using SVN trunk of the datanucleus-appengine plugin, as shown clearly on http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: the Compatibility docs states plugin 2.1 has DataNucleus 3.1+ (core, api-jdo, api-jpa, enhancer) but the maven pom for plugin 2.1.1 has DN [3.1.1, 3.2). why then is plugin 2.1.1 using DN 3.2?

Comment: because Maven is a crap implementation of a reasonable idea, it classifies "less than 3.2" as including 3.2.0.mX as before 3.2. GAE JDO/JPA plugin v2.1.2 fixes the version of DN jars as 3.1.3 or 3.1.4. But then release of the GAE JDO/JPA is outside of my control, just the jars it uses

Answer (score 0):

OK the issue is that the plugin 2.1.1 has a dependency on DN 3.2x.
As @datanucleus has mentioned this is incorrect, it should be limited to DN 3.1.1.

by manual setting the dependency of the plugin to DN 3.1.1. everything now works.

thanks @Datanucleus

Comment: Good that you gave it sorted, but the normal way of doing that is by accepting the answer that gave the solution.

Comment: @Datanucleus The solution suggested was to use plugin 2.1.2. My solution is to use plugin 2.1.1. either way i am happy to upvote your answer.