# google app engine with struts2, spring and JPA using maven

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jpa, datanucleus

I am trying to create an application on google app engine using Struts2, Spring and JPA to connect to appengine datastore.
I have created a maven project and I am able to configure struts2 and spring properly but whenever i try to connect to appengine non-relation database I get the below mentioned error

```
could not resolve type: javax.persistence.Persistence
```

My pom file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<groupId>com.sis.rho</groupId>
<artifactId>rho_v1.0</artifactId>

<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.8.3</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Struts 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Struts 2 + Spring plugins -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <!-- version>3.1.0-m3</version -->
        <version>[3.1.1, 3.2)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
        <version>[3.1.0-release, )</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>[3.1.1, 3.2)</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for log4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- struts 2 velocity dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                <jvmFlags>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=y</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags>
                <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have checked a lot of threads discussing similar issues ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765259/appengine-1-7-4-sdk-and-com-google-appengine-datanucleus-datastoremanager-not-fo)) but none of the fixes provided are able to solve my issue. I included nearly all the dependencies but none worked.
Please help

Comment: I referred to this link http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/orm/datanucleus-appengine/2.1.1/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.1.pom for POM changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue was fixed once i removed optional from geronimo
i am able to run a GAE application with JPA :)

My latest POM where its working is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.sis.rho</groupId>
    <artifactId>rho_v1.0</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <appengine.target.version>1.8.3</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Struts 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Struts 2 + Spring plugins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javax persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <!-- version>3.1.0-m3</version -->
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-release</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- struts 2 velocity dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=y</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                    <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```